# Integration of expression with a function of two variables

Tags: python, function, matrix, sympy, integral

I have this code below, that print a matrix. Each Column of the matrix represent a beam, and each row represents the height of the beam in a speficic point. (See imagem).

```
import numpy as np
import sympy

Fh = 3
E1 = 20 #(N/mm²)
t = 1
L = 5
h_base = 2
h_min = 0
hx = [] 

for x in range(0, L):
    for height_in_x in range(h_min, h_base + 1):
        h = h_base - ((h_base - height_in_x) / L * x)
        hx.append(h)

H_x = np.array(hx, dtype=np.float)
matrix_H_x = np.reshape(H_x, (L, h_base - h_min + 1))        
print (matrix_H_x)

"""
[[ 2.   2.   2. ]
 [ 1.6  1.8  2. ]
 [ 1.2  1.6  2. ]
 [ 0.8  1.4  2. ]
 [ 0.4  1.2  2. ]]
```

Question: Now I need to do a integral using this values: The expression is:

```
result = -1/E1 + sympy.integrate((-Fh * L + Fh * **x**) / (t * **H_x** / 12))
```

But I should keep 3 results independent, for each column (beam)see image

Where:

**x** is a integer that in this case goes from 0 to L

**Hx** is the height of the beam in each **x** distance.

I don't know if the for loop to get the heights was a good solution, maybe I can do everything using only SymPy functions.

[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing for SymPy to do here, because you don't have a symbolic function to be integrated. The functions are presented as sampled data. Integration of sampled data can be done with NumPy or SciPy using methods such as `trapz` (for the trapezoidal rule). In your example,

```
-1/E1 + np.trapz(-Fh*L + Fh*np.arange(0, L) / (t*matrix_H_x.T/12), axis=1)
```

returns `array([337.45, 142.09285714, 83.95])` which are the integrals from the three columns in the matrix.

Explanation: `np.arange(0, L)` is the array of x values (0 to 4). `matrix_H_x.T` is transposed matrix, this transpose is needed to align its axis with L elements with the array of x-values. NumPy broadcasting takes care of computing the values of `-Fh*L + Fh*np.arange(0, L) / (t*matrix_H_x.T/12)` (the end up being a 3 by 5 matrix). Finally, `trapz`, applied along the column dimension (axis=1) integrates each of three rows, returning a number for each.